# Mostrar notificación de alerta tipo Selección al pulsar boton

Tags: java, android

tengo un boton, y la idea es que cuando lo pulse, aparezca un menu de seleccion con strings.
Aquí tengo creado el menu de seleccion con los strings:

```
public class DialogoSeleccion extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final String[] items = {"Español", "Inglés", "Francés"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Selección")

            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Y aqui tengo el boton:

```
<Button
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:background="@drawable/boton_eliminar"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Eliminar encuestas"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Pero al pulsar el boton, la aplicacion se detiene, es decir se crashea.

CatLog:

```
03-09 21:19:04.613 16033-16033/com.example.pablo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button5'
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Editado:**

```
public class DialogoSeleccion extends DialogFragment {

public void onClick(View view) {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final String[] items = {"Español", "Inglés", "Francés"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle("Selección")
                .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        Log.i("Dialogos", "Opción elegida: " + items[item]);
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hola Pablo como estas?, es importante el mensaje en el LogCat porque puede ser una pregunta demasiado amplia !

Comment: Listo, añadido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error

> IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent
>   or ancestor

indica que no encuentra el método, si defines en tu layout el botón,

```
<Button
        ...
        ...
        android:onClick="onClick"
```

el método a llamar mediante el evento click debe definirse como:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view){


     }
```

dentro puedes agregar la creación de tu notificación u `AlertDialog`.

Comment: De esta manera? (post editado)

Comment: No lo logro con ese metodo, me da error al crear el AlertDialog.